# how to use token and secret in Oauth in android

Tags: android, api, oauth, access-token

I'm using Signpost for OAuth in android.

I am getting Http status code 500

and also getting

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature_method"}]}}
```

Here are the codes:

```
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaRegister = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();`enter code here`
            requestParaRegister.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",_firstName));
            requestParaRegister.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",_lastName));  
            requestParaRegister.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",_username));
            requestParaRegister.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", _emailID));
            requestParaRegister.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",_password));

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://*************************/customers");
```

//added setsign method.

consumer.setMessageSigner(new OAuthMessageSigner() {

```
                @Override
                public String sign(HttpRequest arg0, HttpParameters arg1)
                        throws OAuthMessageSignerException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return OAuth.percentEncode(CONSUMER_SECRET) + "&"
                    + OAuth.percentEncode(_tokenSecret);
                    // consumer.setMessageSigner(OAuth.percentEncode(CONSUMER_SECRET));;
                }

                @Override
                public String getSignatureMethod() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

    getOauthConsumer().sign(postRequest);
public OAuthConsumer getOauthConsumer() { 
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET); 
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(_token, _tokenSecret); 
        return consumer; }
```

Comment: `oauth_signature_method` is missing

Comment: How to use that method "oauth_signature_method "

Comment: Please read the manual. It is already mentioned in the response.

Comment: Can you please provide the link of the manual, you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Signpost only supports two sugnature methods which are as "PLAINTEXT & HMAC_SHA1". However in your case you should use "HMAC_SHA1". Refer to the SignatureMethod enum in signpost.

In general you need the following params to sign the request

```
OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY
OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET
OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD
OAUTH_TIMESTAMP
OAUTH_NONCE
OAUTH_VERSION
OAUTH_TOKEN
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
```

You can find out more details about oauth at http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5849.pdf